# Button at the bottom of activity with scrollview

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to make a vertical gallery with images on it and an scrollview to  scroll them and at the end of the activity I want to put a button always visible and I want it to not stay floating over the images.
I don't know how to make it. Any help?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity4"
    android:background="@color/black"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/_003954923"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/_1cuxoy6npl__ss500_"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="349dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/artworks_000569871428_de0u5u_t500x500"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="266dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/artworks_erofeoumtppycjhn_kgoepw_t500x500"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="166dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/buy_the_last_of_us_left_behind_cd_key_pc_download_img1"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="155dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/s5ck0off"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="238dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="321dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Ir a Activity 1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        app:cornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:rippleColor="#33AAAAAA"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want something like the first photo, with a black bottom with the button and over it the scroll. And I have the second photo right now.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/_003954923"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/_1cuxoy6npl__ss500_"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="349dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/artworks_000569871428_de0u5u_t500x500"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="266dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/artworks_erofeoumtppycjhn_kgoepw_t500x500"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="166dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                 app:srcCompat="@drawable/buy_the_last_of_us_left_behind_cd_key_pc_download_img1"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="155dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/s5ck0off"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="238dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="321dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Ir a Activity 1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:rippleColor="#33AAAAAA"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: YES. Could you tell me what did you do exactly?

Comment: Scroll view was not constrainted.